# Angular 7: Checkbox of type radio, use ngModel or change-function?

Tags: angular, typescript, data-binding

```
<label>Yes</label>
<input type="radio" name="dia?" [checked]="info.bDia" (change)="onchangeDia(dia?.checked)">&nbsp;
<label>No</label>&nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="dia?" [checked]="!info.bDia" (change)="onSaveDiabetes(dia?.checked)" />
```

I have an input of type of radio and two checkboxes. I wonder how to get the current value, because I need to change a variable.

```
onchangeDia(val: boolean){
    this.info.bDia = val; // if I log both I get null
}
```

So, I have no clue how to do it. The problem is that jus one checkbox can be checked - I need to check which one. If the checkbox with the label "Yes" `info.bDia` chould change to true.
I would do it with Two-Way-Data-Binding but it does not work for me neither.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to add any function on `change`. Only adding `[(ngModel)]` will work.

Try like this:

```
<label>Yes</label>
<input type="radio" name="dia" [value]="true" [(ngModel)]="info.bDia">&nbsp;

<label>No</label>&nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="dia"  [value]="false"  [(ngModel)]="info.bDia"/>
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-atih7z?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)**